# Use Navigation Bar Title as a Dropdown in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

I'm pretty new to Swift/iOS programming but I'm picking up a lot as I go.

Specifically, I have a Navigation Bar on one of my app's pages that has an edit button to edit the table view that takes up most the page, and an add button to add a new item to the table view. Currently the title just says "Players" because the table is a list of players the user can enter to be kept in the list.

I would like the title to be more of a dropdown menu that can let the user view multiple sets of data being stored (such as multiple lists of different players.)

I can't really provide much in code because there's really nothing to provide yet as I don't know where to start for this particular task. All my current code is mostly just Outlets, Actions, and custom functions for the other UI elements on my page that don't relate to this feature.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your question is "general" in nature, but lacking specific code, I'll give you a general answer with some links to get you pointed in the right direction.

One approach would be to create a popover that displays a `UITableViewController`. Here's a [tutorial from VEA Software](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=48UA06EwfrM) explaining how to create a popover.

Another thing you'll need to know how to do in order to relay stuff from your popover `UITableViewController` to `yourViewController` is `delegate methods`. Here's a nice ["quick and dirty" explanation of delegates](http://useyourloaf.com/blog/quick-guide-to-swift-delegates/).

So basically, what you'd do is you'd create an `IBAction` on `yourViewController` for your dropdown menu. Inside of that method, you'd tell `yourViewController` you want to segue with the following command:

```
self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "popoverSegue", sender: sender)
```

In your `prepareForSegue` method on `yourViewController`, you'd do the configuration you need to do and pass whatever variables you need to pass along to your popover. You'll also want to set `yourViewController` as a delegate of the popover you're displaying.

Over on your `PopoverTableViewController`, you'll need to populate it with data for your `tableView`. In your `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`, you'll want to make use of delegate methods to do stuff on `yourViewController`.

Without specific code, I can only tell you generally what to do and point you toward resources to accomplish it. I hope this is helpful.

Comment: Imagine a brand new single view application with just a view controller script, where a navigation bar and table view are all thats in the storyboard. Assume the table and navigation bar are properly outlet-ed and delegated for use inside the view controller. that's all there is. I'm just using a dictionary to store a key (group name) with an array of players, and the table view is just displayed the array set based on the selected key. Thank you for the links, I will investigate further. I appreciate the effort! I hit the upvote but says it counts but won't display. Hope that helps!